# How to add material ripple to my Angular bootstrap application?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, material-design

I would like to use [material ripple](https://material.io/develop/web/components/ripples/) effect on buttons.

So I added

```
"@material/ripple": "^0.41.0"
```

I have added

```
.btn {
  @include mdc-ripple-surface;
  @include mdc-ripple-radius-bounded;
  @include mdc-states;

  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  padding-top: 6px;

  &[disabled] {
    background-color: $gray1 !important;
    border: 1px solid $gray4 !important;
    color: $gray10 !important;
  }
}

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
```

Looks like this on hover.

[image]

What can be wrong?

Comment: I think this is the native behavior of Angular Material Buttons. You don't really need to install any other module for this. Just introducing Angular Material in your App and using [`MatButton`](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview) should do the trick.

Comment: @SiddAjmera Appreciate. Tried this - the buttons looks like a normal button (not styled)

Comment: How exactly do you want them to be styled?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the native behavior of Angular Material Buttons. You don't really need to install any other module for this. Just introducing Angular Material in your App and using [**`MatButton`**](https://material.angular.io/components/button/examples) should do the trick.

The colors of Angular Material Buttons generally depend on themes. You can create your [**own themes**](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) in order to customize them.

---

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-button-eg?file=app/button-types-example.ts) for your ref.